# I wanna know how can I send the iMacros go to some line

Tags: javascript, imacros

I wanna know how can I send the iMacros jump for some line.
For example:

```
(Line 1) VERSION BUILD=9002379
(Line 2) TAB T=1
(Line 3) URL GOTO=www.google.com
(Line 4) URL GOTO=www.facebook.com
(Line 5) BACK TO THE LINE 3
```

it's like a LOOP but I need to know a command to send the iMacros back to the line 3 without loop command because I'll use this command in a IF/ELSE case with this kind of LOOP inside, and this will be a good way to me.

Something like this exist? HELP, it's very important.

Sorry for my english, I don't know speak very well this language.

Thank You.

---

Like I said, I can't use LOOP, because in my code **I wanna the iMacros click in a button EVERYTIME the word "Russian" are on the screen.** And if I put a LOOP just will check one time or how times I said and when the word don't exist will be continue on the loop, and I need this check everytime but when the word don't exist stop with the loop and continue the rest of the code, did you understand?
**It's something like a infinite loop but when haven't the word Russian on the screen stop the loop and continue the rest of the code.**

My english is a crap, sorry...
Please, help me, it's VERY VERY VERY important!

Comment: there is no such thing in imacros

Answer (score 2):

It would be near impossible through the standard iMacros scripting.  Instead, use a VBA script to loop through the actual iMacros script.

Answer (score 0):

```
(Line 1) VERSION BUILD=9002379
(Line 2) TAB T=1
SET LOOP! 1
(Line 3) URL GOTO=www.google.com
(Line 4) URL GOTO=www.facebook.com
(Line 5) BACK TO THE LINE 3
```

maybe this will work.
I think it will but had no time to test it

Answer (score 0):

@Plantje that's not going to work I believe.

@Morantis Though you can have a look at: [Loop after Query/Login](http://wiki.imacros.net/Loop_after_Query_or_Login)

Maybe you'll find something here that you are looking for. Maybe tweak it a little since it's a simple example with going to google pages and save the result etc ...